# How to loggin with Facebook using Amazon cognito for android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Does anyone knows how to loggin with Facebook using Amazon cognito? I'm following Amazon's documentation but it's not working.
I get Facebook's token but I can't pass it to Amazon's server.

Does anyone knows/have an example? Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognito has an [Android demo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) that uses Facebook available.